# Show progress bar for a background Operation

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Im new to eclipse rcp.

Context:

Im performing a login operation using eclipse rcp, i'v cretead a view which accepts username and password from the user and when user clicks on Login Button the code checks against the database and if valid a new view is shown to the User else shows error invalid login.

So here in the above i desperately wanted to show a progress bar(that waits for sometime) while its checking against the database in the background.

can i know how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ProgressMonitorDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/ProgressMonitorDialog.html) to achieve what you want. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html#progressreport) on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse RCP based application, then you can even implement your "Operation" as extending "org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job". Your app ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor has to have set in preWindowOpen(): configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);

After your JOB is started is automatically shown down there in progress.

You can even add progressView via Extension to your app, and when you click down there on progress your operation pops up in ProgressView where you can even cancel :)

Hope it helped.